# mysql sum same column on 2 group by

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `stock` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`quantity` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
 `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `codf` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `ean` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

how can i get total quantity for both codf and ean for each product

so for example if i have this stock

```
 id | p_id | quantity |
 1  | 1    | 1        |
 2  | 2    | 2        |
 3  | 1    | 3        |
 4  | 3    | 4        |
```

and those products:

```
 id | codf | ean |
  1 |   1  |  11 |
  2 |   1  |  12 |
  3 |   2  |  13 |
```

i need  to get

```
 codf 1 = 6
 codf 2 = 4
 ean 11 = 4
 ean 12 = 2
 ean 13 = 4
```

so i need to sum quantity grouping by distinct codf and sum quantity grouping by distinct ean, ean is also unique

Now i do it in php, i select all rows, left join products and i use arrays to group them and get the final quantity like so:

```
select s.quantity, p.codf,p.ean from stock s left join products p on p.id = s.p_id
```

and i have this php:

```
 while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
      $total[$r[ean]] += $r[quantity];
      $total[$r[codf]] += $r[quantity];
  }
```

and display for each product the quantity we have in stock

```
codf = a number for similar products
ean = a unique number a product can have
```

but it would really help me if i can do it in mysql

Thanks and sorry if i misspelled something, english is not my primary language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ce
     , val
     , SUM(quantity) total 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT 'codf' ce, codf val, s.quantity FROM products p JOIN stock s ON s.p_id = p.id
        UNION
       SELECT 'ean' ce, ean, s.quantity FROM products p JOIN stock s ON s.p_id = p.id
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY ce, val;
```

Comment: Thanks you, it is about 0.1 seconds faster than my approach, so it's a nice improvement :)